# Explain the decimals

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a decimal in the form of `<float>, <precision>`, you draw the graphical representation of the decimal part (i.e. fraction) of the float. Examples:

1. Input: `6.75, 4`, output:

   ```
   6||| 7
    ----
   ```

   `6.75` (first number from the input) is the number to explain, `4` (the second number from the input) is the number of dashes below the pipes.  `6` is the floored 6.75, `7` is the ceiled `6.75`. The number of pipes is the `decimal part of first input number * second input number`.
2. Input: `10.5, 6`, output:

   ```
   10|||   11
     ------
   ```
3. Input: `20.16, 12`, output

   ```
   20||          21
     ------------
   ```

   `.16` actually takes 1.92 pipes, but since I can't draw 1.92 pipes, I ceil it to 2.
4. Input: `1.1, 12`, output:

   ```
   1|           2
    ------------
   ```

   `.1` is 1.2 pipes in this case, so it's floored to 1 pipe.
5. Also, an edge case. Input: `5, 4` (i.e. the number is an integer), output:

   ```
   5    6
    ----
   ```

---

- The number to explain is the positive float, limited only by your language abilities.
- The precision number is an even integer, greater than 2 (i.e. minimal required precision is 4). It can be arbitrary large too.
- *>= n.5* pipes are rounded up, to *n+1* (i.e 1.5 is rounded to 2 and 2.5 is rounded to 3). *< n.5* pipes are rounded to *n* (i.e. 1.4 is rounded to 1 and 2.4 is rounded to 2).
- If it would be more convenient for your language, you can take the input as an array, e.g. `[6.75, 4]`. If you take the input in the reversed order, i.e. `[4, 6.75]`, please specify it in your answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what the desired output format is?

Comment: @isaacg I've shown four example outputs. What's unclear?

Comment: There seem to be a few corner cases uncovered. E.g. input `5.0 4`: does it draw from `5` to `6` or from `4` to `5`, or is either acceptable? Input `1.25 2`: does it have 0 or 1 `|`s, and why (i.e. what's the rounding rule)? Does the first number in the input have to be positive? What's its maximum precision and magnitude? Does the second number in the input have to be positive? If it's negative, do we draw backwards?

Comment: @Peter Clarified.

Comment: I don't think you've covered the rounding rule.

Comment: @Peter If you are about "What's its maximum precision and magnitude?" - I don't understand why it should be limited by anything rather than the programming language float / int limits.

Comment: Re the rounding rule, consider `1.125 4` and [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5608/194). If precision and magnitude should be bounded by the language limits, state so - although the question of what those limits are is a bit subtle for integer-only languages which might effectively need to multiply the fpart of the first input by the second input without overflow.

Comment: @Peter Tried to clarify.

Comment: Very sloppily expressed. You're using 'decimal' to mean (1) input string, (2) number, and (3) fractional part. It doesn't mean any of those things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### CJam, 32 bytes

```
l~1md@:X*mo'|*XSe]1$)NW$s,S*'-X*
```

Takes the precision first and the decimal second, separated by a space.

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~1md%40%3AX*mo'%7C*XSe%5D1%24)NW%24s%2CS*'-X*%0A%0A%5DoNoNo%7D%2F&input=4%206.75%0A6%2010.5%0A12%2020.16%0A12%201.1%0A4%205%0A4%201.125)

#### Explanation

```
l~   e# Read input and evaluate, pushing precision and decimal on the stack.
1md  e# Divmod 1, separating the decimal into integer and fractional part.
@:X  e# Pull up precision, store in X.
*mo  e# Multiply precision by fractional part and round.
'|*  e# Push that many vertical bars.
XSe] e# Pad with length X with spaces.
1$)  e# Copy integer part and increment.
N    e# Push linefeed.
W$   e# Copy integer part.
s,   e# Get number of digits as length of string representation.
S*   e# Push that many spaces, to indent the hyphens correctly.
'-X* e# Push X hyphens.
```

Comment: Yep, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 119 bytes

```
a=ToString;b=Array;a[c=Floor@#]<>{b["|"&,d=Round[#2#~Mod~1]],b[" "&,#2-d],a[c+1],"
"," "&~b~IntegerLength@c,"-"&~b~#2}&
```

I tried... Testing:

```
In[1]:= a=ToString;b=Array;f=a[c=Floor@#]<>{b["|"&,d=Round[#2#~Mod~1]],b[" "&,#2-d],a[c+1],"\n"," "&~b~IntegerLength@c,"-"&~b~#2}&;

In[2]:= f[6.75, 4]

Out[2]= 6||| 7
         ----

In[3]:= f[10.5, 6]

Out[3]= 10|||   11
          ------

In[4]:= f[20.16, 12]

Out[4]= 20||          21
          ------------

In[5]:= f[1.1, 12]

Out[5]= 1|           2
         ------------

In[6]:= f[5, 4]

Out[6]= 5    6
         ----
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a working demo, or it's not possible?

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript ES6, <s>105</s> 104 bytes

```
(f,p)=>(i=f|0)+("|".repeat(j=(f-i)*p+.5|0)+" ".repeat(p-j))+(i+1)+(`
`+i).replace(/\d/g," ")+"-".repeat(p)
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to, um, how do you type ՊՓԼՃՐՊՃՈԲՍԼ anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the dashes were part of the output, I thought they were just there to visualise the spaces.

Comment: `(f,p)=>(i=f|0)+("|"[r="repeat"](j=(f-i)*p+.5|0)+" "[r](p-j))+(i+1)+("\n"+i).replace(/\d/g," ")+"-"[r](p)`

Comment: Oh yeah, replace `\n` with an actual newline. And make sure to wrap it in template strings.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>253</s> <s>206</s> 181 bytes

*Saved 47 bytes thanks to @Kenney by inlining conditions and variables used once, and sorting out redundant variables.*

*Saved 25 bytes again thanks to @Kenney by inlining 2 loops with ternary operators.*

Pure String Manipulation:

Inlined loops version (181 bytes):

```
String m(float f,int p){int g=(int)f,i=0;String h="",q=""+g;int c=q.length();for(;i<c+p;)h+=i++<c?" ":"-";for(i=c;i<p+c;)q+=i++<c+Math.round((f-g)*p)?"|":" ";return q+(g+1)+"\n"+h;}
```

4 loops version (206 bytes):

```
String m(float f,int p){int g=(int)f,i=0;String h="",q=""+g;int c=q.length();for(;i++<c;)h+=" ";for(;i<=c+p;i++)h+="-";for(i=c;i<c+Math.round((f-g)*p);i++)q+="|";for(;i++<p+c;)q+=" ";return q+(g+1)+"\n"+h;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
String m(float f,int p){
//initialize some useful values, d is the number of pipes needed
int g=(int)f,d=Math.round((f-g)*p),i=0;
String h="",q=""+g;//append the floored value to the pipe string first
int c=q.length();
for(;i<c;i++)h+=" ";//pad hyphen string with spaces for alignment
for(++i;i<=c+p;i++)h+="-";//append hyphens
for(i=c;i<c+d;i++)q+="|";//append pipes
for(;i<p+c;i++)q+=" ";//append spaces for padding
return q+(g+1)+"\n"+h;}//concatenate the strings in order, separating the strings with a UNIX newline, and return it.
```

Working example here at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/spK7j3). The full program accepts STDIN input as
`<float>,<precision>`.

NOTE: Java's `Math.round(float)` rounds using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`as the default, which is the OP's required behaviour.

The output of the test cases provided was diff-matched to what the OP provided.

Comment: I hope you don't mind! You forgot to remove `a` (never used), setting you at 233. You could save another 23 to get at 210 bytes: replacing `q.length()` with `b` saves 13: `int g=(int)f, b=(""+g).length(), c=b, i=0;`. Incrementing the iterator in the condition of the `for` saves 6, and inlining `d` (used once) saves 4: `int c = b; for(;i++<b;)h+=" ";  for(;i++<=b+p;)h+="-";  for(i=c;i<c+Math.round((f-g)*p);i++)q+="|";  for(;i++<p+b;)q+=" ";`.

Comment: Also, someone suggested using an actual newline instead of the escape sequence, but since I'm on Windows, that's a CRLF, 2 bytes anyway given the `\n`

Comment: Nice - yes, `b` became obsolete aswell ;-) You can still save 1 byte in the 2nd for: `for(;i++<=c+p;)`. You _could_ save the file with unix line endings on windows, but unfortunately [Java doesn't allow multiline strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)..

Comment: @Kenney, no. I tried that. It leads to misaligned hyphens. Java is not the right man for the job, anyway.

Comment: I got it down to 181 bytes by using only 2 for loops: `for(;i<c+p;)h+=i++<c?" ":"-";for(i=c;i<p+c;)q+=i++<c+Math.round((f-g)*p)?"|":" ";`

Comment: @Kenney, looking at it, it did occur to me to use conditionals at the time, but I never got around to doing it. I (normally) prefer verbose code anyway. Perhaps you should post this on your own? I really don't want to plagiarize your effort.

Comment: @Kenney, I'll just copy-paste it then. I hope you don't mind, and I also hope you ran the tests correctly (bit short on time here).

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
Uf +'|pA=ºU-Uf)*V c)+SpV-A +Uc +R+SpUk l)+'-pV
```

Just a bunch of adding and repeating.

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VWYgKyd8cEE9KChVLVVmKSpWIGMpK1NwVi1BICtVYyArUitTcFVrIGwpKyctcFY=&input=Ni43NSA0)

Comment: `(U-Uf)` is the same as `U%1`, saving two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 113 bytes

```
(%)=replicate.round
s=show
x!y|(n,m)<-properFraction x=[s n,(y*m)%'|',(y-y*m)%' ',s$n+1,"\n",s n>>" ",y%'-']>>=id
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ 20.16 ! 12
20||          21
  ------------
```

`properFraction` splits the decimal into it's integer and fraction part. The output is a list of the parts (initial number, bars, spaces, ...) which is concatenated into a single string (via `>>=id`).

Comment: Is it possible to see an online demo of this?

Comment: @nicael: [demo](http://ideone.com/7piaaC) (with a `main` wrapper for a full program).

Comment: Looks like everything's okay (btw: tested [there](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php), think that it's a more convenient compiler).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 49 bytes

```
2#1\tYUbiXK*Yo'|'1bX"tnKw-Z"hb1+YUhht4Y2m13*_45+c
```

Uses [release 6.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) of the language/compiler. Runs on Matlab or Octave.

Takes numbers in the same order as in the challenge.

#### Examples

```
>> matl
 > 2#1\tYUbiXK*Yo'|'1bX"tnKw-Z"hb1+YUhht4Y2m13*_45+c
 >
> 20.16
> 12
20||          21
  ------------

>> matl
 > 2#1\tYUbiXK*Yo'|'1bX"tnKw-Z"hb1+YUhht4Y2m13*_45+c
 >
> 5
> 4
5    6
 ----
```

#### Explanation

```
2#1\       % implicit input 1st number. Separate decimal and integer part
tYU        % duplicate integer part and convert to string
biXK*Yo    % input 2nd number. Copy it. Multiply by decimal part of 1st number and round
'|'1bX"    % row vector of as many '|' as needed
tnKw-Z"    % row vector of as many spaces as needed
h          % concat horiontally
b1+YUhh    % integer part of 1st number plus 1. Convert to string. Concat twice
t4Y2m      % detect numbers in this string
13*_45+c   % transform numbers into spaces, and non-numbers into '|'
           % implicitly display both strings
```

Comment: Do you have an online interpreter?

Comment: Not yet :-( Runs on Matlab or Octave

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 90 bytes

```
print$f,"|"x($d=.5+($b=pop)*(($a=pop)-($f=0|$a))),$"x(1+$b-$d),$f+1,$/,$"x length$f,"-"x$b
```

Expects input as commandline arguments. Save in a file (say `90.pl`) and run as `perl 90.pl 6.75 4`

***With comments***

```
print $f,                        # floored input (initialized below due to expr nesting)
      "|" x ($d=.5+              # rounded pipe count (`x` operator casts to int)
             +($b=pop)           # second argument  (executed first)
             *( ($a=pop)         # first argument   (executed second)
               -($f=0|$a) )      # minus floored first argument = fractional part
            ),
      $"x(1+$b-$d),              # spaces
      $f+1,                      # floored + 1
      $/,                        # newline
      $"  x length $f,           # 2nd line alignment
      "-" x $b                   # the 'ruler'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>116</s> 108 bytes

```
def f(F,P):l=int(F);h,p=str(l+1),int((F-l)*P+.5);l=str(l);print(l+"|"*p+" "*(P-p)+h);print(" "*len(l)+"-"*P)
```

[trinket.io link](https://trinket.io/python/080858ae81)

Thank you to Seeq for saving a few characters.

#### First version:

```
def f(F,P):
 l=int(F)
 h,s,p=str(l+1)," ",int((F-l)*P+.5)
 l=str(l)
 print(l+"|"*p+s*(P-p)+h)
 print(s*len(l)+"-"*P)
```

Ungolfed version:

```
def frac(F,P):
        low = int(F)
        high = low+1
        pipes = int((F-low)*P+.5)
        print(str(low)+"|"*pipes+" "*(P-pipes)+str(high))
        print(" "*len(str(low))+"-"*P)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working demo?

Comment: This trinket.io link should work: https://trinket.io/python/409b1488f8

Comment: It actually takes less characters to just use the space literal than store it. You can also just join all the lines with `;`. You only use `h` once, so you should inline it, too.  Ought to save some chars.

Comment: @Seeq Good catch on the space literal.  Early on I was printing the white space padding at the end of the second line; after I realize that was unnecessary, I didn't double check the code for savings.  The `h` is trickier.  For the concatenation and `len` function in the last two rows to work, `l` has to be a string, so `h` would need to be replaced with `str(int(l)+1)`.  Setting `h` before converting `l` saves a few characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stackgoat](https://github.com/vihanb/Stackgoat/blob/master/stackgoat.js), <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```
CFv1%C*D'|^w1P-Y^vHXNY^w'-^
```

Similar to most of the other answers. I'll see if I can golf more. The input can be comma separated, space separated, or almost anything separated.

### Explanation

```
CF   // Input, floored, push to stack
v1%  // Decimal part
C*   // Times second part
D    // Duplicate that result
'|^  // Repeat | by previous number
w    // Second input
1P   // Move # of |'s to the top of stack
-    // Subtract
Y^   // Repeat " " by above number
vH   // Ceil first input
X    // Newline
Z+   // Add to 
N    // Get length of first #
Y^   // Repeat by spaces
w'-  // Repeat - second input times
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 157 bytes

Long, but can't find a shorter solution

```lua
function f(d,n)r=""a=math.floor(d)d,s=d-a,a..r for i=1,#s do r=r.." "end for i=1,n do s,r=s..(i-.5>n*d and" "or"|"),r.."-"end s=s..a+1 return s.."\n"..r end
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
function g(d,n)
  r=""
  a=math.floor(d)
  d,s=d-a,a..r                         -- d now contains its decimal part
  for i=1,#s do r=r.." "end            -- padding the hyphens
  for i=1,n
  do
    s,r=s..(i-.5>n*d and" "or"|"),r.."-"
    -- s is concatenated with a "|" if i-.5>n*d, a space otherwise
  end
  s=s..a+1
  return s.."\n"..r
end
```

You can test lua [online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), the following test cases could be useful :)

```lua
function f(d,n)r=""a=math.floor(d)d,s=d-a,a..r for i=1,#s do r=r.." "end for i=1,n do s,r=s..(i-.5>n*d and" "or"|"),r.."-"end s=s..a+1 return s.."\n"..r end
print(f(16.75,4))
print(f(5,4))
print(f(20.16,12))
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <del>233</del> 231 bytes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
i,n,l;main(c,v)char**v;{double m;l=atol(v[2]);n=(int)(modf(atof(v[1]),&m)*l+0.5);c=printf("%.f",m);for(;i++<l;)putchar(i>n?32:'|');printf("%.f\n",m+1);printf("%*s",c,"");for(;--i;)putchar(45);}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
i,n,l;

main(c,v)
char**v;
{
    double m;
    l=atol(v[2]); /* Get length from command line */
    n=(int)(modf(atof(v[1]),&m)*l+0.5); /* Get number of pipes and lower limit */
    c=printf("%.f",m); /* print lower limit */

    /* print pipes and spaces */
    for(;i++<l;)
            putchar(i>n?32:'|');

    /* print upper limit */
    printf("%.f\n",m+1);

    /* print spaces before dashes */
    printf("%*s",c,"");

    /* print dashes */
    for(;--i;)
            putchar(45);
}
```